# Method should be called when a view gets into focus

Tags: objective-c, inappsettings

in my iOS project I use [**InAppSettings**](https://bitbucket.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/wiki/Home). This is [missing a delegate in the modal view controller for willDismiss.](https://bitbucket.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/issue/29/missing-delegate-for-modal-view-controller)

So when the modal view gets dismissed I want a method to be called in my main view controller.  How can I do this? Is there a method in a view controller that gets triggered whe the view is in focus again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
BOOL settingsLaunched = NO;

-(void)presentInAppSettingsViewController
{
    //Show the settings modal view controller here

    //Set our flag
    settingsLaunched = YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if(settingsLaunched)
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

these will get called on the view after dismissing a modal dialog it presents

```
- (void) viewWillAppear
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```